# How to free hand draw curve object with drawing tablet? 2.8

Tags: bezier-curves

Hey i figured out easiest way of creating custom neon light sign would be to draw it with curves. I know in 2.79 such option exists - https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/modeling/curves/editing/draw.html "The Curve draw tool allows you to free-hand draw curves." Where is it in 2.8 ?

I want to achieve this: https://warszawskieneony.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/28h28ac.jpg?w=440 but for much longer text 'Happy new year' or sth stylized

I could do it manually but that would be really a lot of work fiddling with curve vectors few hours for sure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a *Curve > Bezier*, go in *Edit* mode, and choose the *Draw* tool:

[image]

Comment: I swear i used google to no avail. Thank you! that was really easy, I am embarrassed now a bit. Looks like somebody has to feed those sweet results to web scraper eh. You made my day!